# Tk GUI Scrollbar

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I've a problem that the scrollbar being made appears to be in the left, i've tried many combinations so as to move it to the right.

My code looks like this:

```
set dataSheetFrame($k) [frame $curPath($k).frame1 -height 420 -relief groove]
#pack $dataSheetFrame($k)
scrollbar $dataSheetFrame($k).vscroll1 -highlightthickness 0 -orient vertical \
        -width 15
set viewC1($k)  [canvas $dataSheetFrame($k).canvas -height $cHeight1 -width $cWidth1 \
        -yscrollcommand "$dataSheetFrame($k).vscroll1 set" \
        -scrollregion "0 0 $cWidth1 $cHeight1" -bg black]
grid $dataSheetFrame($k).vscroll1 -in $dataSheetFrame($k) -row 0 -column 0 \
        -rowspan 1 -columnspan 1 -sticky news
grid $viewC1($k) -in $dataSheetFrame($k) -row 0 -column 1 \
        -rowspan 1 -columnspan 1 -sticky news
grid rowconfigure $dataSheetFrame($k) 0 -weight 1 -minsize 0
grid columnconfigure $dataSheetFrame($k) 0 -weight 1 -minsize 0
$viewC1($k) create line $cellWidth 0 $cellWidth $cHeight1 -width 3 -fill white
$viewC1($k) create line [expr $cellWidth + $dWidth] 0 \
        [expr $cellWidth + $dWidth] $cHeight1 -width 1 -fill white
$viewC1($k) create line [expr $cellWidth + 2 * $dWidth] 0 \
        [expr $cellWidth + 2 * $dWidth] $cHeight1 -width 1 -fill white

for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $cfgNames]} {incr i} {
    set name [lindex $cfgNames $i]
    $viewC1($k) create text [expr $cellWidth / 2] \
            [expr $offsety + $i * 30 ] -anchor center -width 0 \
            -text $name -justify center -fill white
    set j 1
    foreach process {Slow Typical Fast} {
        set y [expr $offsety + $i * 30 ]
        if {[info exists tpfValues($name,$process)]} {
            $viewC1($k) create text [expr $cellWidth + \
                    $j * $dWidth - $dWidth / 2] $y \
                    -anchor center -width 0 -fill white \
                    -text $tpfValues($name,$process) \
                    -justify center
        }
        $viewC1($k) create line 0 [expr $y + 15] $cWidth1 \
                [expr $y + 15] -width 3 -fill white
        incr j
    }
}

set offsetTpf [llength $cfgNames]

for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $tpfNames]} {incr i} {
    set name [lindex $tpfNames $i]
    $viewC1($k) create text [expr $cellWidth / 2] \
            [expr $offsety + $offsetTpf * 30 ] -anchor center -width 0 \
            -text $name -justify center -fill white
    set j 1
    foreach process {Slow Typical Fast} {
        set y [expr $offsety + $offsetTpf * 30 ]
        if {[info exists tpfValues($name,$process)]} {
            $viewC1($k) create text [expr $cellWidth + \
                    $j * $dWidth - $dWidth / 2] $y \
                    -anchor center -width 0 -fill white \
                    -text $tpfValues($name,$process) \
                    -justify center
        }
        $viewC1($k) create line 0 [expr $y + 15] $cWidth1 \
                [expr $y + 15] -width 3 -fill white
        incr j
    }
    incr offsetTpf
}
$dataSheetFrame($k).vscroll1 configure -command "$viewC1($k) yview"
pack $dataSheetFrame($k) -side left
```

Please help me with this..

Thanks

Comment: You should try to isolate your problem and provide us with a more condensed code listing. This will be better not only for us, but also for you.

Answer (score 3):

You are putting it in column 0, so of course it will appear on the left. You need to put it in a column number greater than the column that you are placing the canvas in.

When you are just learning how to do use the grid geometry manager, it *really* helps if you actually draw the GUI out on a piece of graph paper. Doing that makes it crystal clear which column each widget goes in, and whether or not they need to span additional rows or columns.